# ERROR: LoadError: Could not find imagemagick binary. Is it installed? in Julia

Tags: julia

I am seeing this when I try to call `write()`.

```
ERROR: LoadError: Could not find imagemagick binary. Is it installed?
Stacktrace:
 [1] #write#6(::Float64, ::Function, ::String, ::Frames{MIME{Symbol("image/png")}}) at /Users/chandlerkilpatrick/.julia/packages/Reel/hVzPi/src/Reel.jl:76
 [2] write(::String, ::Frames{MIME{Symbol("image/png")}}) at /Users/chandlerkilpatrick/.julia/packages/Reel/hVzPi/src/Reel.jl:64
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /Users/chandlerkilpatrick/.julia/dev/VDPTag2/test/gif.jl:34
```

I did not see anything on the ImageMagick docs as to how I can fix this. Does anyone have an suggestions?

EDIT: I switched to Julia 1.2 and here is the issue I get now:

```
ERROR: LoadError: error compiling _plot!: error compiling _display: could not load library "libGR.so"
dlopen(libGR.so.dylib, 1): image not found
Stacktrace:
```

2nd edit: When I try to do the brew install of ImageMagick, I get a long print out and then:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "imagmagick" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
Chandlers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ chandlerkilpatrick$
```

Comment: Have you tried `]build ImageMagick`?

Comment: Yes, it builds fine

Comment: Could the issue be that I am on Julia 1.0.3 with   [6218d12a] ImageMagick v0.7.3?

Comment: I tried it on Julia 1.2 as well an got the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the package you're trying to use (`Reel.jl`) does not attempt to ship its binary dependencies such as `imagemagick` or `ffmpeg`.  It relies on you to install them globally on your system.  You can see this by looking at the source code, and how the package is looking for these binaries [0].

I am guessing that you use MacOS based on the file paths in your error message; so try using Homebrew to install them via `brew install ffmpeg imagemagick`. This should bring in the required binary dependancies.

[0] https://github.com/shashi/Reel.jl/blob/eac0ead6aa22d04a3d0c14b774d5b2a0c6b75970/src/Reel.jl#L71-L77

[1] https://brew.sh

Comment: Getting a different error now. Edited the post above

Comment: After running `brew install ffmpeg imagmagick` I still get the same thing